# How to change existing timestamp in JSONB object to another timestamp format in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Table `user_record` has column `info` which is returning following data whereas `info` is a `jsonb` column. 
**QUERY:** `Select info from user_record;`
Result:

```
{"someId": "XXFUN0123XX", "age": 43, "updatedAt": "2017-02-18 00:00:00"}
```

Now The question is specifically about `updatedAt` field from json response

`select info ->> 'updatedAt' from user_record where id='XXFUN0123XX';`

*Result: 2017-02-18 00:00:00*

I have to update all the timestamps of `updatedAt` fields of `info` column of `user_record` table with this format -> `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS+02:00` so when I do `select info ->> 'updatedAt'`, I would get the result like this -> `2017-02-18T00:00:00+02:00`. 
I've already tried multiple ways and read the documentation but couldn't find a proper solution. Following is one query which I was trying to do

```
UPDATE user_record SET info = info || jsonb_build_object('updatedAt', 
select to_timestamp(info ->> 'updatedAt','YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS+02:00') from user_record where id ='XXFUN0123XX')) where id = 'XXFUN0123XX';
```

In above query, I am trying to pick up `updatedAt` from json object from inner query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `jsonb_set` to make the changes in the jsonb. and use `to_char` instead of `to_timestamp` like below:

```
update user_record
set info=jsonb_set(info,'{updatedAt}',to_jsonb(to_char((info ->> 'updatedAt')::timestamp,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS+02:00')))
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8a7ba286aceaaaad19d2314aadeb0534)

Comment: Great Answer. It would be great if you can add some detail about query that how it works.